# ¿Como evitar que json_encode escape caracteres?

Tags: php, json

Hola tengo un `array` de objetos el cual tiene la siguiente forma:

```
[
   {
      id: 1,
      Nombre: "Asociación",
      Url: "https://google.com"
   }
]
```

Cuando lo paso por `json_encode` me codifica las vocales o caracteres especiales.

```
json_encode($array);

[
  {
     id: 1,
     Nombre: "Asociaci/u001n",
     Url: "https:\/\/google.com"
  }
]
```

Necesito que no me escape los `/` ni los caracteres especiales.

```
 json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Pero esto que hago no aplica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

es que estas pasando los diferentes argumentos con `,` cuando deberia ser por `|`

web oficial: 
[json_encode](http://docs.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php#example-4460)

**ejemplo:**

```
$a =array(
      "id"=> 1,
      "Nombre"=> "Asociación",
      "Url"=> "https://google.com"
   );

 echo json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: gracias. encontré la misma respuestas en la documentación de php https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php